# Fundamental Algorithm Running time Big O() calculation question

Tags: c++, big-o

I have this algorithm

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<sqrt(n); j++) {
  }
}
```

Is this Big O running time O(n*sqrt(n)) => dropping sqrt => O(n)?

or I keep the O(n*sqrt(n))?

Comment: If you have a constant times N you can drop the constant, but sqrt(N) is not constant.

Comment: You can't drop the `sqrt(n)` from the complexity just because it's less than `n`. It's a multiplicative term in the complexity and it scales with `n`.

Comment: Since you are calling `sqrt(n)` on every iteration of the inner loop, it also depends how fast you can calculate sqrt(n).